# A difference behavior between a deque and a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator, deque, std

I could successfully implement LRU cache using a list and a (hash)map. I am wondering why there was wrong behavior when I used a deque instead of a list. Let me explain my approach briefly.

1. Find a value using a key from the map. The map returns an iterator of the list or deque that holds its value.
2. Iterator should be updated 
   2.1. Erase the existing node from the map and the list or deque.
   2.2. Push a new node into the front of the list and the map also holds the key and an iterator of the new node as a value.

So my question is: Why did I get a wrong result when I used a deque instead of a list? I guess a deque internally has a list of chunks and it would make a problem. But, I am not sure a root cause.

Here is a reproducible code. The expected result is "9 29 9" and I could see the correct answer when using a list. But the wrong result "9 29 29" is returned when using a deque.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
using vi = vector<int>;
using vvi = vector<vi>;

using pii = pair<int, int>;
#if 1
using List = deque<pii>;
#else
using List = list<pii>;
#endif
using ListIter = List::iterator;
using Map = unordered_map<int, ListIter>;

class LRUCache {
  size_t capacity;
  List lru_list;
  Map map;

public:
  LRUCache(size_t capacity) : capacity(capacity) {}

  void put(int key, int value) {
    Map::iterator miter = map.find(key);
    promote(key, value, miter != map.end() ? miter->second
      : (lru_list.size() == capacity) ? --lru_list.end() : lru_list.end());
  }
  int get(int key) {
    Map::iterator miter = map.find(key);
    if (miter == map.end()) return -1;
    pii v = *(miter->second);
    promote(v.first, v.second, miter->second);
    return v.second;
  }

  void promote(int key, int value, ListIter iter) {
    if (iter != lru_list.end()) lru_list.erase(iter);
    lru_list.push_front({key, value});
    map[key] = lru_list.begin();
  }
};

void run(LRUCache& cache, vvi& vv) {
  for (auto& e : vv) {
    if (e.size() > 1) cache.put(e[0], e[1]);
    else cout << cache.get(e[0]) << endl;
  }
}

void test1() {
  LRUCache cache(10);
  vvi vv {
    {10,27}, {8,10}, {6,29}, {1,9},
    {1}, {6}, {1}
  };
  run(cache, vv);
}

int main() {
  test1();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please confine your question to 1 main question rather than two seperate ones

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated my question.

Comment: You also need a [mcve] instead of an external link

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. I have added a compact reproducible scenario instead of providing a link with a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, but I'm guessing that your problem is iterator invalidation. In `promote` you either `push_front` or `erase` an element from the underlying container. If the container is a `list`, no iterators are invalidated. If the container is a `deque`, then some of the iterators will be invalidated.

[CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) has a section on iterator invalidation.